# Invalid resource ID Error, When tesing an Azure Web App Bot in Web Chat

Tags: azure, nlp, chatbot, azure-cognitive-services

I followed this azure's guide to build a simple question answering bot: https://microsoftlearning.github.io/AI-900-AIFundamentals/instructions/04d-create-a-bot.html#create-a-bot-for-the-knowledge-base

Everything works fine until deployment(last section).

When I deploy, an Web App Bot is created. But when try to test it in the web chat I get an " Invalid resource ID" error.

[image]

What can I do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by **redeploying**.

[image]